# Where should one store a confidential data after decrypting it from JWT token

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt, authorization, access-token

We can decrypt the confidential data that we obtain from any JWT with some node/ npm packages ex: [JWT Decode Library- StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61556071/how-to-decode-jwt-token-by-using-jwt-decode-library-in-reactjs). But where exactly do we store it so it is only accessible to the javascript or the front-end and not to the user. Data in localstorage, sessionstorage could easily be fetched by the user and doesn't really seem like an ideal solution.

I have tried using redux but once we refresh the screen, we lose the data and the user needs to login again. Which is like a huge downgrade to the User Experience

Comment: I am using ReactJS as a front end tool

Comment: Every data in frontend is accessible by the user

Comment: Ideally store only info like userId, or any public info, you should try to get user info from api call when its needed, you can store access token which has minimal user info like userId

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Even the data we store in redux?

Comment: So, we can store the token which is like a bunch of random strings and pass it along with any API request but I am trying to render screens based on role of the user. I don't think it's ideal to request for user role every time I call an API right? @Azzy

Comment: Yes, even in redux

Comment: @KonradLinkowski So, what's the ideal way to implement role based screen rendering?

Comment: It doesn't mean you can't store data in `localStorage`. Users usually already know their data

Comment: @KonradLinkowski yeah I mean if I am an admin and I know that my data is stored in local storage then it's okay because I am already an user with highest privileges but what if I am just a normal user and the application stores role in localstorage with a key (say role = user) and use that value to render screens. If the user is good with browsers, it is just a matter of time before they realize they could change the role to admin/ superuser to get highest privileges. Local storage data is not just accessible but also editable.

Comment: token can be stored in local/session storage

Comment: If it's some permissions config, it can be sent from the server once, the ui doesn't have to know about roles and stuff, it can be given as a config/permissions info, so that ui can render accordingly

Comment: @rahuuzz, yes but I need to store some more confidential data and process it in the UI

Comment: @Azzy My only concern is it doesn't just involve one page, if that's the case then I wouldn't bother storing. Every user has his own config and based on that screens are rendered. The config should not be visible to user, if it is they can easily change it to access other unauthorized sites.

Comment: Is it possible to explain a scenario, so that we understand it better, since I assume only one user wil log in at a time, and all pages can show only authorized info, so all the permissions can be stored in a context on login, I feel I am missing something